# check condition in foreach loop with dynamic variable in knockout js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have html file at the path
/var/www/html/nelson-avnet-app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/list.html

```
<!-- ko if: (visible)-->
<div class="field addresses">
    <div class="control">
        <input id="query" type="text" name="query" data-bind="textInput: query, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keyup: check }"/>
        <div class="shipping-address-items">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: customTotal" />
            <!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->
                <!-- ko if: element.index < customTotal -->
                    <h1>show value</h1>
                <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

if I use if statement as `<!-- ko if: element.index < 2 -->`
Then it works fine
but it not work with dynamic value like

```
<!-- ko if: element.index < customTotal -->
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **customTotal** in below js file if not You need to add **customTotal** variable in js file

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js

defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/list',
        visible: addressList().length > 0,
        rendererTemplates: [],
        customTotal: 2
    },
```

You can extend/override this file on your custom module

Comment: I already have customTotal as listed the code below, and its value is 3. But I can not apply condition on html page based on it.



defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/list',
        visible: addressList().length > 0,
        rendererTemplates: [],
        customTotal: ko.observable(0),
    },